# Why this program throws ClassCastException?

Tags: java

My program is

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String.valueOf(hoge());
    }

    static <E> E hoge() {
        return (E) "hoge";
    }

}
```

result is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.base/java.lang.String cannot be cast to [C
    at stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I'm using Java9.
The return type of `hoge` is ambiguous.  I think it should be compile error.
And why compiler choose `String.valueOf(char[])` instead of `String.valueOf(Object)`?

Comment: The error is fairly obvious.  You're trying to cast some generic object to a `String`.  Why would you want to do this?  There's little practical gain in combining both generics *and* casting like this unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @Makoto What part are you talking?  I'm not trying to cast any object to `String`.

Comment: You're right; you're trying to cast a `String` to an arbitrary object.  There's really no value in doing this.  I'm confused as to why you would want to do this at all since it's clear that the compiler isn't going to be able to detect this kind of exception.

Answer (score 1):

There are several overloaded String.valueOfs, only two of them have object parameter valueOf(char[]) and valueOf(Object), others are primitive, like String.valueOf(int). Since exact return type is unknown, but it's an object type, compiler has chosen valueOf(char[]). I do not know which part of JLS explains that behavior, but it is similar to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    x(null);
}

static void x(char[] x) {
    System.out.println("char[]");
}

static void x(Object o) {
    System.out.println("Object");
}
```

compiler chooses char[]

Answer (score 0):

When multiple overloaded methods are applicable for method resolution, *the most specific method* is chosen.

This can result in some odd behaviour if one of the argument types is generic and unrestricted, or `null`, because they match any declared method argument type.

In your case, `char[]` in `valueOf(char[])` is more specific than `Object` in `valueOf(Object)` - that's the reason.

This is specified in [JLS 15.12.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> **Choosing the Most Specific Method**
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.

The result of the section goes into detail how this is done.

`java.lang.Object` is not special in this respect; you'll get the same issue with the following code:

```
public class Main {

    private static String valueOf(Number x) {
        return null;
    }
    private static String valueOf(Integer x) {
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        valueOf(hoge());
    }

    static <E> E hoge() {
        return (E) "hoge";
    }

}
```

In the above case, the method call will go to `valueOf(Integer)` because `Integer` is more specific than `Number`.